# Is storage Vue.js instance in sessionStorage a acceptable paradigm?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, session-storage

I want to implement axios global error handler by show a prompt, but the prompt component is bound to the Vue instance, so I have to implement global error handler by:

```
mounted() {
    SessionStorage.vueInstance = this;
}
```

in my `App.vue` file and handle error globally by call `SessionStorage.vueInstance.$Message.error({...})`

Is this a acceptable paradigm? Or it's just a "better not"?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is only using `sessionStorage` as a replacement for the `window` object. It doesn't give you anything. It does not make the key-value persistent or shared. Except perhaps permit you to avoid name conflicts with the window keys.

I have no idea if any standard requires Storage objects to have writable keys. There might be a browser where Storage objects are frozen.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your message component can be decoupled from the current view component. Like [my gist](https://gist.github.com/fimars/64d68b1e9c1254b656bc7413caa20d56) show.